# How to rewrite paths on single SSL secured subdomain to secure web apps on other subdomains using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cakephp, silverstripe

Let's say I have an SSL secured domain at secure.domain.com.

I also have a web application (using silverstripe) at www.domain.com and another at app.domain.com (using CakePHP)

I would like specific areas of www.domain.com and app.domain.com to utilize SSL, and thus must somehow rewrite the paths using the subdomain with the installed SSL certificate.

So for example, secure.domain.com/ss/* should rewrite to www.domain.com/* and similarly, secure.domain.com/app/* should rewrite to app.domain.com/*.

The challenge, however, is that both www.domain.com (SilverStripe) and app.domain.com (CakePHP) have their own complex rewrite rules, and I can't seem to build an htaccess script that successfully retains the functionality of the respective applications...

FYI Assume I have the directory structure /public_html and webroots assigned to the apps as follows:
www.domain.com -> /public_html/subdomains/www
app.domain.com -> /public_html/subdomains/app
secure.domain.com -> /public_html/subdomains/secure

Has anyone accomplished something similar to this before?

Comment: It'll cost you an extra $25 or so, but why not just get a SSL certificate for www.domain.com and app.domain.com and avoid all the trouble?

Comment: Unfortunately, our 1&1 managed dedicated host only allows one SSL cert :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most elegant way is to simply [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink) the SSL subdirectory to the apps folder, so they're basically the same directory.

```
/public_html/app
/public_html/subdomains/secure.domain.com -> /public_html/app
```

That is, if your host gives you this option.

Comment: That did it... had to make a few tweaks to the .htaccess files inside the respective app directories, but all is working now. thanks!